# Unable to add my database postgresql on heroku nodejs DEPLOYMENT ERROR

Tags: node.js, database, git, heroku, deployment

```js
const express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passwordHash = require('password-hash');
const cors = require('cors');
var knex = require('knex');
const register = require('./controllers/Register');
const signin = require('./controllers/Signin');
const profile = require('./controllers/Profile');
const image = require('./controllers/Image');

//var connectionString = "postgres://*USERNAME*:*PASSWORD*@*HOST*:*PORT*/*DATABASE*"

const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: true,
    }
  })

const app=express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
 res.send("it is working")
})

app.post('/signin',(req,res)=>{signin.handleSignIn(req,res,db,passwordHash)})

app.post('/register',(req, res)=>{register.handleRegister(req, res, db,passwordHash)})

app.get('/profile/:id', (req,res)=>{profile.handleProfileGet(req,res,db)})

app.put('/image',(req,res)=>{image.handleImage(req,res,db)})

app.post('/imageurl',(req,res)=>{image.handleApiCall(req,res)})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()=>{
 console.log(`app is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
})
```

This is my server.js file
unable to figure out error I added all the changes using git add then used git commit -m "changed port" git push heroku master

git logs --tail (getting error here)

```html
rohit@rohit-Vostro-3583:~/Desktop/smartbrainAPI$ heroku logs --tail
2020-04-19T11:38:00.460877+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-19T11:38:04.722372+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-19T11:38:04.722404+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-19T11:38:04.722404+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-04-19T11:38:04.722405+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064464+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/server.js:21
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064499+00:00 app[web.1]: db.connect();
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064500+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064500+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064504+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: db.connect is not a function
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064505+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:21:6)
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064506+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064506+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064506+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064507+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064507+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
2020-04-19T11:38:05.064508+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
2020-04-19T11:38:05.070768+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-04-19T11:38:05.071050+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-04-19T11:38:05.072100+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-04-19T11:38:05.072245+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-04-19T11:38:05.072422+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-04-19T11:38:05.072557+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the node@1.0.0 start script.
2020-04-19T11:38:05.072688+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-04-19T11:38:05.077328+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-19T11:38:05.077531+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-04-19T11:38:05.077662+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-04-19T11_38_05_073Z-debug.log
2020-04-19T11:38:05.151564+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-19T11:39:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-19T11:39:26.226816+00:00 app[api]: Deploy cf844469 by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-19T11:39:26.226816+00:00 app[api]: Release v20 created by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-19T11:39:26.932529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-19T11:39:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-19T11:39:34.492601+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-19T11:39:34.492681+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-19T11:39:34.492682+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-04-19T11:39:34.492683+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-19T11:39:35.127798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-19T11:39:35.085705+00:00 app[web.1]: app is running on port 31626
2020-04-19T11:53:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-19T11:53:22.454500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-04-19T11:53:22.458236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-04-19T11:53:22.256081+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-19T11:53:22.256081+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 5c8d0f48 by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-19T11:53:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-19T11:53:27.273472+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-19T11:53:27.273493+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-19T11:53:27.273493+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-04-19T11:53:27.273493+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-19T11:53:27.734584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-19T11:53:27.649117+00:00 app[web.1]: app is running on port 30116
2020-04-19T11:53:47.570119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=3624d2fe-2e3a-4e0c-99d0-3f06882d864c fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=181 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:54:51.279964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=2ee65713-56e6-45b2-ba85-8d5aac800275 fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:59:28.292870+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/register" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=ef749eda-243d-4d3f-aedd-92c995701359 fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:59:32.895743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=34278a55-19f1-4ee1-9eae-0d9d60e0a6bc fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:59:33.562086+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=2087a4b7-1701-4c2c-91de-3ee3085e861d fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=41ms status=400 bytes=267 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:59:33.878990+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=b47adc7b-6c48-4d42-b69f-12544286a6d4 fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=400 bytes=267 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:59:34.454755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=518c21f9-5d5f-4860-b2a8-e48c84096f8e fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=400 bytes=267 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:59:34.565367+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=f63998c3-7850-435c-85d2-efbbde3040ef fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=400 bytes=267 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:59:34.871204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=a2322ada-8faf-4964-b5ea-76c68bba69b7 fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=400 bytes=267 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:59:34.992259+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=7e896a02-2d8f-4713-99fb-26ae2bb01a02 fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=400 bytes=267 protocol=https
2020-04-19T12:31:42.742729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-04-19T12:31:42.746564+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-04-20T03:36:37.247697+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2020-04-20T03:36:37.262797+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-04-20T03:36:42.828317+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-20T03:36:42.828354+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-20T03:36:42.828355+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-04-20T03:36:42.828355+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-20T03:36:43.203099+00:00 app[web.1]: app is running on port 11796
2020-04-20T03:36:43.849848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-20T03:36:45.324642+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=40c07246-2b5b-4079-bda3-04b6347c2290 fwd="157.39.3.225" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=181 protocol=https
2020-04-20T03:36:45.998463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=e3b41154-ef4f-4823-833f-74a8dc7b29c2 fwd="157.39.3.225" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=426 protocol=https
2020-04-20T03:54:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-20T03:54:26.193272+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1da13236 by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-20T03:54:26.193272+00:00 app[api]: Release v22 created by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-20T03:54:27.082771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-04-20T03:54:27.096340+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-04-20T03:54:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-20T03:54:31.467317+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-20T03:54:31.467339+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-20T03:54:31.467340+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-04-20T03:54:31.467340+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-20T03:54:31.978215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-20T03:54:31.771327+00:00 app[web.1]: app is running on port 36319
2020-04-20T03:57:17.192518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/register" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=5854e26c-7119-4abc-bdd5-b398b8f051d0 fwd="157.39.119.21" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https
2020-04-20T03:57:17.634127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=9bbc745e-1e7f-47c6-90d9-08e1aac92589 fwd="157.39.3.225" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https
2020-04-20T03:57:19.675739+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=8108baef-41d0-4b0c-a5dc-3967fe2098e4 fwd="157.39.3.225" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=400 bytes=267 protocol=https
2020-04-20T04:18:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-20T04:18:52.526320+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1c1b07e7 by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-20T04:18:52.526320+00:00 app[api]: Release v23 created by user rohitjain991100@gmail.com
2020-04-20T04:18:53.554662+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-04-20T04:18:53.558703+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-04-20T04:18:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-20T04:18:57.947008+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-20T04:18:57.947025+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-20T04:18:57.947026+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-04-20T04:18:57.947026+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-20T04:18:58.227322+00:00 app[web.1]: app is running on port 12966
2020-04-20T04:18:58.560135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
^C
rohit@rohit-Vostro-3583:~/Desktop/smartbrainAPI$ heroku pg:info
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           0/20
PG Version:            12.2
Created:               2020-04-19 08:42 UTC
Data Size:             8.3 MB
Tables:                2
Rows:                  1/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Cont

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

This is what error I am getting This is showing that i have database also for it

Help me in finding out what to change
I ahve done git add .
git commit
git push heroku master

Heroku open is also working finely

Dont know what error is

```html
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "no",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "clarifai": "^2.9.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "knex": "^0.20.13",
    "password-hash": "^1.2.2",
    "pg": "^8.0.1",
    "serve": "^11.3.0"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json file

Comment: The error log says `TypeError: db.connect is not a function`, but there is no mention of `db.connect()` in `server.js` (at line 21)

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari  I previously added db.connect() in the server.js but afterwards i have removed it and used commands git add .  then git commit  and then git push heroku master

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what error your facing. Your logs indicate build was successful. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I accept heroku open is also working properly .But the issue is that my database is not able to connect with the server after i connected it .                                      I face these type of lines lines  on logs            at=info method=POST path="/signin" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=f63998c3-7850-435c-85d2-efbbde3040ef fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=400 bytes=267 protocol=https                     whenever i click register or login button on my app

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari   I used same articles to connect both       JUST DONT KNOW WHAT DOES THESE LINES SAY        2020-04-19T11:53:47.570119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=3624d2fe-2e3a-4e0c-99d0-3f06882d864c fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=181 protocol=https
2020-04-19T11:54:51.279964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/" host=warm-reef-38212.herokuapp.com request_id=2ee65713-56e6-45b2-ba85-8d5aac800275 fwd="157.39.217.175" dyno=web.1 co

Comment: It basically shows the type of requests made at different paths and what status code the server responded back with.